# Refresh Image Content

Tags: android, android-gallery

Here I trying to develop paint application based on specification. I used **andengine** and **android** both for this application development.

I can able to save user created image and load that particular image into canvas. These both operation work perfect for me. But when I open gallery view then it didn't show latest content of the image.

It shows data when it first time created in gallery view. But when I load that image it show correct image on canvas. I think it was a problem of gallery refresh so that I write following code for that purpose.

```
pexelMimics.sendBroadcast(new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"
                            + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

But this code can only able to show new created image into gallery but content update can't get reflected into gallery. I searched other post but I could not able to found useful content.

So my friends please help me to come out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MediaScanner` may be helpful on this occasion.

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://your_file_path"
                        + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()))
```

It will scan whole external storage for searched media file.
**Reference from here**:

- http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg63884.html

Comment: Using above way, I try to refresh gallery but I couldn't get success. My file explorer show latest content of image but my load gallery view shows images old content.

Comment: you may use notifyDataSetChange() that interacts with UI.See some helpful info's http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687723/update-android-image-gallery-with-newly-created-bitmap,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15043401/image-not-showing-up-in-gallery

Comment: Thanks, Yet I have not checked your both link so at present I will not reply you about this. But after research I found that I have to refresh thumbnail of the gallery. I have not checked this thing also but I want some suggestion from you that this was the reason for not getting latest content in gallery.

Comment: ya that is a point you need to look up,but have a try with those links i provided.